# Azure devops GitVersion task failed

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, gitversion

As of this week I have noticed that when creating a new repository in azure devops the "master" branch no longer exists but was replaced by a "main" branch.

When I configure the pipeline for that new repository I use the GitVersion task that I have always used to version my artifacts in azure devops but since this change was made I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a 'develop' or
> 'master' branch, neither locally nor remotely.

Anyone know how I could solve this problem?

I would really appreciate your support.

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? What hasn't worked?

Comment: I have looked on the web and in the official azure devops documentation but I can't find something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a lot of tools or services in the git ecosystem is moving away from 'master' as the default branch:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/azure-repos-default-branch-name/

No GitVersion release actually does support this new branch name.

See https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/2433

Fix is there https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/pull/2367

So you have 2 possibilities :

- switch back to 'master' branch (see the setting to set in Azure Devops in the first link above) and you will have to rename the branch yourself.
- update GitVersion configuration while waiting for the release with the fix. See https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/2433#issuecomment-725586659

Comment: Thank you very much, you have been a great help